# How do I load any file from assets folder with extension(.json) in C# Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, file-io, base64

I'm trying to load multiple file from my assets directory with extension .JSON and want to show to my UI element of my game,
like I've created some JSON file in assets folder of Unity and I want to load only file with .json extension and also wants convert that JSON file into Base64 then Image texture.

I've tried this:

```
bool check1 = file.EndsWith (".json");
if (check1)
{
        Debug.Log ("JSON File found: " + file);
}
```

Please suggest me with any example, Thanks.

Unity Version: 2020.3.11f1,
language: C#

Comment: Why would you want to store an Image as JSON?

Comment: @oRoiDev I have to send this data to server. So I cannot send textures directly in web request and I need to convert it into basestring and the whole data needs to be converted as JSON.

Comment: @AliHussain why can't you just send binary data in a webrequest?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open something during runtime, I believe it must be located in the resources folder. This is usually considered a bad practice so I'd try to get around it.

Now, I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do but if you want to send a texture to a server, then I'd look into the JsonUtility class and serializable classes. Textures can be encoded to PNG in runtime as well, so it fits into a Serializable class.

You'll essentially generate a json request as you go, with a structure defined by the class you've created

EDIT: Here is the code that will generate a json encoded string from a texture

```
using UnityEngine.Serialization;

//the struct
[System.Serializable]
public struct SerializableExample
{
    public string name;
    public byte[] tex;
}

//code for generating json with image
string serializeJsonImage(string name, Texture2d tex) {
    SerializableExample example = new SerializableExample();
    example.name = "example name";
    example.tex = tex.EncodeToPng();
    return JsonUtility.ToJson(example); 
}
```

Comment: can you please demonstrate with an example, It would be great help to understand well, am new in Unity and C#.

Comment: The code is in the edit